# If an HR person or recruiter requests sensitive information, should I provide it to them?

Tags: recruitment

Is it safe to divulge sensitive personal information to an employee of a company's HR department, over e-mail or the phone, either before or after receiving an offer? Should I do anything to double-check that the request is legitimate?

Comment: What kind of sensitive personal information do you mean?

Comment: [Health info](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27651/giving-health-information-for-health-insurance-to-recruiter); [Driver's license](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54419/recruiter-requesting-driver-license-for-initial-job-offer); [Social Security](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/24241/is-it-okay-to-give-recruiters-last-four-digits-of-my-ssn); [National Insurance](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56704/should-i-give-a-recruiter-my-national-insurance-number)

Comment: I agree with your duplicate choice, thanks @DavidK!

Answer (score 5):

I found this online recently and thought it would be good to raise awareness of recruitment fraud for anyone not aware of how this method may work:

> It has been brought to our attention that third parties have been
>   contacting job seekers and applicants to make fictitious job
>   offers and obtain sensitive personal and financial information. These
>   individuals may use the names of our recruiting and human
>   resources staff and may ask the candidates to provide personal
>   identifying information, send money, or cash checks. To help you avoid
>   becoming a victim of this fraud, we wanted to make you aware of this
>   situation and let you know the following:
>
> We and our affiliated and subsidiary companies never solicit
>   money, collect fees, or ask for financial information or passwords
>   from job applicants. We would not ask you to provide sensitive
>   identifying information, such as social security number, drivers’
>   license number, or banking information over the phone. If you are
>   contacted about a job offer at our company, please verify the person’s
>   name, title, and address in your communications and then contact them
>   through our main switchboard at (telephone number). If you suspect you have
>   been the victim of recruiting fraud, contact your local law
>   enforcement agency immediately.